# Plugin with id 'jacoco-android' not found

Tags: android, filter, camera, open-source

I cloned [phimpme](https://github.com/rohit08102003/phimpme-android) this is a open-source for camera filters i open this in android studio but i am getting this error "Plugin with id 'jacoco-android' not found." there was no link that can auto identify problem and download missing component.

i tried to reinstall android studio but no success